# Odd SyntaxError with Ext.js

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm working with Ext.js on a project and I'm getting odd behavior from it.

The code I'm using throws `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` and it's only thrown in the following 2 cases:

```
var thing = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    constructor : function(){
        this.superclass.constructor.apply(this, [{  //Throws SyntaxError
```

or

```
var thing = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    constructor : function(){
        this['superclass'].constructor.apply(this, [{  //Throws SyntaxError
```

However, it works in the following cases:

```
this.superclass().constructor.apply(this, [{
```

and

```
this['superclass']().constructor.apply(this, [{
```

I'm entirely confused as to how `this.superclass.constructor.apply` throws a `SyntaxError` whereas `this.superclass().constructor.apply` doesn't. The former seems to be entirely valid syntax, so I'm not entirely sure what the issue is.

Would anyone be able to elaborate on why that'd be invalid syntax?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT:** I had wondered whether or not Ext.js was throwing the `SyntaxError`, but there was nothing I noticed when skimming search results that would convince me that Ext.js is actually throwing it. If I am incorrect in that, and Ext.js is throwing it, please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure it's a SyntaxError? Or is it a TypeError instead?

Comment: There's no invalid syntax in your question. Can you post more code? Sometimes the line number the error gives you can be a little off.

Comment: There's really no more code to it than that. I'm definitely sure it's a `SyntaxError`, and the only thing I'm changing is the `()` after `superclass`. Without the `()` it is a `SyntaxError`, with the `()`, it's fine.

Comment: That's just really odd. Is it a SyntaxError in every browser? Can you reproduce the error here? http://jsfiddle.net/aBcSQ/

Comment: It's only in Chrome, I'll test it in other browsers and let you know.

Comment: Does the SyntaxError say something about "invalid character"? If so, did you happen to copy/paste this code from a website?